# change cell content view when custome view added to cell

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have created one uiviewcontroller with xib to adding in the uitableview cell. here is the code for that.

```
@interface CustomeCellHome : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgViewBack;

    // will have number of labels and imageviews.
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imgViewBack;


@implementation CustomeCellHome
@synthesize imgViewBack;
```

all this IBOutlet connected to xib.

now i am adding this to my uitableview cell. here is code for that.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 150;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
//    }


    CustomeCellHome *objCell = [[CustomeCellHome alloc] init];
    [objCell.view setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:objCell.view];

    objCell.imgViewBack.image = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"unsel.png"];

    [objCell release];
    return cell;
}
```

now i want to change this imgViewBack image on selection of row. here is code for that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CustomeCellHome *objCCell = [[CustomeCellHome alloc] init];
    objCCell.view = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    objCCell.imgViewBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sel.png"];
```

}

but my imgViewBack is not changing its image. don't getting what is wrong with this. any suggestion for that ? any suggestion will be appreciated .

Comment: and by the way you need to do i guess ,
CustomeCellHome *objCCell = [[CustomeCellHome alloc] init];
because it is not initialized ..

Comment: Thanks for answering iremk, i have tried this. now it is not crashing but it is not changing the imageview's image. i have updated the code.

Comment: ok then please try to do [cell.contentView addSubview:objCell.view]; at the end , i'm nearly sure this will solve the problem , because i am not sure if tableview uses reference copy or deep copy but just try this please :)

Comment: application getting crashed with the error. "Unable to restore previously selected frame".

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CustomeCellHome *objCCell = [[CustomeCellHome alloc] init];
objCCell.imgViewBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sel.png"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:objCCell];

does this work?

Comment: i have tried it. its not working.giving error . "Unable to restore previously selected frame"

Comment: ok my thought was the problem was about : objCCell.view = [cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]; but then it is not , let me check it again , i'll comment soon..

Comment: ok. i will wait for your comment.

Comment: Is there a special reason why u use a separate viewController to hold all the cell's views? Why not just adding the views to the cell itself?

Comment: i have number of labels and imageviews. And it is easy to manage with uiviewcontroller's xib instead of creating it with code.

Comment: U can also create a custom UITableViewCell in xib... If u r using a ViewController just because u can layout the views with xib I don't think u should.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a viewController like u do (again probably this is not what u need), I can see few problems with your code.

1) Instead of `[objCell.view setTag:indexPath.row];` use `[objCell.view setTag:indexPath.row+1];` otherwise u will have a problem when indexPath.row=0 (I think 0 is also the tag of the superview).

2) Don't release the viewController, if u need one keep it around.
(but u will need to save it in some data structure so later u can release it...)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    // u will have problems reusing those cells...
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   // if(cell == nil) 
   // { 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        CustomeCellHome *objCell = [[CustomeCellHome alloc] init];

        [objCell.view setTag:indexPath.row+1];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:objCell.view];

        objCell.imgViewBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];

        //[objCell release]; // don't release now, add it to some data structure so u can release later
   // }

    return cell;
}
```

2)  Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` retrieve the cell's viewController and change his `imgViewBack` property.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // get the cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // get the cell's viewController
    UIView *aView = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row+1];
    CustomeCellHome *objCCell = (CustomeCellHome *)[aView nextResponder];

    // update the image
    objCCell.imgViewBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
}
```

This will change the image, but this is not a perfect solution, u will have problems if u r reusing cells... Try rethink if u really need to use the viewController.